# update status value in sharepoint list using power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have two fields named as Status and Approved.
In my form when approver selects the option either approved or reject, the result will get save in the approved field.
Now I want to change the status field also as per the result save in the approved field to Approved or Rejected.

I tried this by using update item action in power automate flow and it is not working. It is calling the same thing in a loop. It is also showing warning that this action will trigger an infinite loop.

Can anyone please suggest me any solution with this action in flow.

Comment: What’s your trigger on this flow?

Comment: trigger I am using is .. When an Item is created or modified.

Comment: So you want to keep the two fields in sync, is that right?  Will the user change one and then you want to automatically update the other?

Comment: yes, as the approver approves or rejects the item from the approved dropdown and submits it. Accordingly it will also update the status value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add trigger conditions to your flow so that it will only fire when a specific set of conditions are met.

This is a basic example that you can try and incorporate into your own flow.

My list has two specific fields, `Field1` and `Field2`.  As per your trigger, when an item is created or modified, I only want to trigger the flow when those two fields are not equal and if they're not, the flow will update `Field2` with the value from `Field1`.

[image: List]

This removes the recursive nature of the flow as it will do the check prior to actually executing.

My expression for the trigger is shown below ...

[image: Trigger Conditions]

... and that setting can be found in the settings of the trigger ...

[image: Settings]